# Unable to Claim a device using QR code scanner in Thingsboard mobile application app

Tags: qr-code, device, barcode-scanner, thingsboard

I am working on thingsboard device claiming feature.I was trying to claim a device using QR code scanner but didn't get it. I have set up the Action for the QR code scanner but I was unable to claim the device in the mobile Application.
I have used the following json format in the QR code generation.
{

“deviceName”:"deviceName","secretKey":"secretKey"

}

I have included the following code for 'QR code scanner'-- 'Mobile Action' to claim the device through scanning.

```
var $scope = widgetContext.$scope;
var $injector = $scope.$injector;
var $translate = $injector.get(widgetContext.servicesMap.get('translate'));
var deviceService = $injector.get(widgetContext.servicesMap.get('deviceService'));
var deviceNotFound = $translate.instant('widgets.input-widgets.claim-not-found');
var failedClaimDevice = $translate.instant('widgets.input-widgets.claim-failed');
var claimDeviceInfo = JSON.parse(code);
var deviceName = claimDeviceInfo.deviceName;
var secretKey = claimDeviceInfo.secretKey;
var claimRequest = {
  secretKey: secretKey
};
deviceService.claimDevice(deviceName, claimRequest, { ignoreErrors: true }).subscribe(
  function (data) {
    widgetContext.showSuccessToast('Device \'' + deviceName + '\' successfully claimed!');
    widgetContext.updateAliases();
  },
  function (error) {
    if(error.status == 404) {
      widgetContext.showErrorToast(deviceNotFound);
    } else {
      if (error.status !== 400 && error.error && error.error.message) {
        showDialog('Failed to claim device', error.error.message);
      } else {
        widgetContext.showErrorToast(failedClaimDevice);
      }
    }
  }
);

function showDialog(title, error) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    widgetContext.dialogs.alert(title, error).subscribe();
  }, 100);
}
```

Kindly, I request you to go through my issue.

I have succeeded in claiming a device by entering 'deviceName' and 'secretKey' manually but i was unable to do it using QR code scanner.
I would like to know if there are any errors in my process. Can you share the detailed information about claiming Device using QR code scanner.